# Adjusting p-values (mixed effects logistic regression)?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, p-value

Quick question regarding adjustung p-values....

I preformed a logistic mixed effects regression model and used Wald likelihood ratio test to select model parameters.

I received comments back from a journal reviewer stating that I should use Holm-Bonferroni correction for p-values due to multiple comparisons....

I did not think that adjusted p-values were required when performing mixed effects logistic regression.... am I incorrect in my assumption?
any comments/suggestions greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: I think you either used the Wald test or the likelihood ratio test, they are not the same. If I were reviewing this for a journal I would be more worried about your having performed variable selection than any issue of multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Wald likelihood ratio test to select model parameters will invalidate any p-values and confidence intervals, as well as biasing estimates - unless you adjusted for that somehow. Thus, the reviewer is right to highlight this topic, if you had not done some appropriate there - especially so, if the model building is an important part of the paper. Just reporting estimate, CI and p-value after model selection as if not model selection had occured is wrong and misleading.

I am not sure that using a Bonferroni-Holm correction is an approach for dealing with that. Perhaps it is possible to use it for that purpose at least to correct the p-values, but it may be extremely conservative.

If you then afterwards are performing multiple comparisons across multiple levels of a random effect, then there's some people that would argue that no correction is needed (see e.g. Gelman et al.'s "Why we (usually) don't have to worry about multiple comparisons" article) - but others (perhaps including your reviewer) may disagree. If you are comparing multiple levels of some fixed effects factor, then it is clearer that there is a multiple comparison issue (although some might still argue against the need for type I error correction if this is rather exploratory and you do not want to use a hypothesis testing approach claiming "statistical significance").

Answer (score 1):

Multiple testing corrections are not inherently linked to an particular analytic tool, just to hypothesis testing in general.

p.s. I would suggest using something less conservative than the bonferroni correction, especially if you have A LOT of tests. For example, look into controlling the false discovery rate, rather than the family-wise error rate.